# Change URL for Facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to change the url of an existing Facebook share?

Recently I changed the site urls from http to https and now I don't see the the number of shares made under http.

The Open Graph Object Debugger is showing the correct information, including the 301 redirect from http to https.

Answer (score 0):

In the perspective of the Open Graph Scraper the two urls `http://somesite` and `https://somesite` are different. There is no way to transfer the share information.